# Azure Diagnostic settings created via PowerShell not visible in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-diagnostics

I'm adding Diagnostic Settings via (Az) PowerShell to all my Logic Apps in defined Resource Group.

```
$Workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name "dev-shared-monitoring-loganalytics" -ResourceGroupName "dev-shared-monitoring"

$LogicApps = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/workflows -ResourceGroupName "*-dev-*"

foreach ($LogicApp in $LogicApps) {
    Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $LogicApp.ResourceId -WorkspaceId $Workspace.ResourceId -Enabled $true -Name "SendToMonitoring"
}
```

After succesfull creation, I can fetch them all via PowerShell Get-AzDiagnosticSetting but they aren't visible in the azure portal:

[image: Diagnostic Settings not visible]

Comment: try to refresh your portal or change to another browser? The scripts also could work on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the commands provided by you and was able to see the Diagnostics settings on the portal:

[image]

Try opening a new window or open the portal in incognito mode.

Comment: after waiting some minutes the portal also reflects the changes made by the script